# Pandas dataframe - fillna with last of next month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I've been staring at this way too long and I think Ive lost my mind, it really shouldn't be as complicated as I'm making it.

I have a df:

| Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-17 |
| 2022-04-15 | 2022-04-15 |
| 2022-03-03 | NaT |
| 2022-04-22 | NaT |
| 2022-05-06 | 2022-06-06 |

I want to fill the blanks in 'Date2' where it keeps the values from 'Date2' if they are present but if 'Date2' is NaT then I want it to be the last date of the subsequent month from 'Date1'.

In the example above, the 2 NaT fields would become:

| Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-04-30 |
| 2022-04-22 | 2022-05-31 |

I know I have to use .fillna and the closest I've come is this:

```
df['Date2'] = (df['Date2'].fillna((df['Date1'] + pd.DateOffset(months=1)).replace)).to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
```

This returns the first of the month. However, it returns the first of the month for all rows (not just NaT rows) and it is returning the first of the month as opposed to the last of the month.

I'm pretty sure my parenthesis are messed up and I've tried many different combinations of - timedelta and similar.

What am I doing wrong here? TIA!

Comment: When you say subsequent month did you mean that of the next row? Or just the same row? (Your example is ambiguous)

Comment: next month in the row.

Comment: MAR > APR,
APR  > MAY

Comment: So next month in the **same** row?

Comment: yes, <b>same</b> row

Comment: Then a simple `pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2)` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted in two ways given the provided example.

##### End of month of the next row's date 1 (which **now** does not seem to be what you want)

You need to use `pd.offses.MonthEnd` and `shift`

```
df['Date2'] = (df['Date2']
               .fillna(df['Date1'].add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd())
                                  .shift(-1))
               )
```

##### Next month's end (same row)

If you want the next month end of the **same row**:

```
df['Date2'] = (df['Date2']
               .fillna(df['Date1'].add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2)))
               )
```

Output:

```
       Date1      Date2
0 2022-04-01 2022-06-17
1 2022-04-15 2022-04-15
2 2022-03-03 2022-04-30
3 2022-04-22 2022-05-31
4 2022-05-06 2022-06-06
```

Comment: Why do you use `shift`? Now we have the same answer :)

Comment: Because the question can be interpreted in two ways and the example is ambiguous. I added an update to my answer

Comment: @onyambu I'm typing on a phone (which is slow), I didn't see any other answer when I updated mine;)

Comment: @onyambu. It doesn't matter if the answer has already been posted. The important thing is that the OP has at least one correct answer which is the case in all answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MonthEnd` and `loc`:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
>>> df.loc[df['Date2'].isnull(), 'Date2'] = df['Date1'] + pd.DateOffset(months=1) + MonthEnd(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MonthEnd` with an offset of 2 (current month and next month):

```
df['Date2'] = df['Date2'].fillna(df['Date1'].add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2)))
print(df)

# Output
       Date1      Date2
0 2022-04-01 2022-06-17
1 2022-04-15 2022-04-15
2 2022-03-03 2022-04-30
3 2022-04-22 2022-05-31
4 2022-05-06 2022-06-06
```